Model Accuracy Jumps to 1.0000 After First Epoch Completion
As I said in title when I start training my model. It accuracy jumps directly to 1 after completion of 1st epoch and model loss stuck at 2 point something.
I am using a text retrieval model but there is a problem during model training. This first one training type, I used just 800 examples for training and 200 for validation. it reaches to accuracy 1.0  after completion of just first epoch, you can see.
Epoch 1/50
Finding embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Text embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Text embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Global Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Local Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Image embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Image embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Logits shape: (None, None)
Text similarities shape: (None, None)
Image similarities shape: (None, None)
Targets shape: (None, None)
Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float16)
Finding embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Text embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Text embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Global Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Local Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Image embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Image embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Logits shape: (None, None)
Text similarities shape: (None, None)
Image similarities shape: (None, None)
Targets shape: (None, None)
Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float16)
     39/Unknown - 12s 63ms/step - loss: 366.7810 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1154
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
     79/Unknown - 18s 109ms/step - loss: 234.1003 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1218
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    119/Unknown - 24s 127ms/step - loss: 161.7107 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1261
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    159/Unknown - 31s 136ms/step - loss: 121.8854 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1219
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    199/Unknown - 37s 141ms/step - loss: 97.8084 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1219
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    239/Unknown - 44s 145ms/step - loss: 81.7869 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1224
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    279/Unknown - 50s 147ms/step - loss: 70.3594 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1281
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    319/Unknown - 56s 148ms/step - loss: 61.7977 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1305
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    359/Unknown - 63s 149ms/step - loss: 55.1439 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1260
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    399/Unknown - 69s 150ms/step - loss: 49.8242 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1310
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    439/Unknown - 75s 151ms/step - loss: 45.4740 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1327
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    479/Unknown - 82s 152ms/step - loss: 41.8503 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1435
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    519/Unknown - 88s 152ms/step - loss: 38.7851 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1917
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    559/Unknown - 94s 152ms/step - loss: 36.1586 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2496
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    599/Unknown - 100s 153ms/step - loss: 33.8829 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2997
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    639/Unknown - 106s 152ms/step - loss: 31.8921 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3435
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    679/Unknown - 113s 153ms/step - loss: 30.1359 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3822
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    719/Unknown - 119s 153ms/step - loss: 28.5751 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4166
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    759/Unknown - 126s 154ms/step - loss: 27.1788 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4473
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    799/Unknown - 132s 154ms/step - loss: 25.9223 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4750
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    839/Unknown - 138s 154ms/step - loss: 24.7856 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    879/Unknown - 144s 154ms/step - loss: 23.7523 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5228
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    918/Unknown - 151s 155ms/step - loss: 22.8316 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5430
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    959/Unknown - 158s 155ms/step - loss: 21.9444 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5626
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    999/Unknown - 164s 155ms/step - loss: 21.1491 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5801
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1039/Unknown - 171s 156ms/step - loss: 20.4149 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5962
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1079/Unknown - 177s 156ms/step - loss: 19.7352 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6112
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1119/Unknown - 183s 156ms/step - loss: 19.1041 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6251
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1159/Unknown - 190s 156ms/step - loss: 18.5166 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6381
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1199/Unknown - 196s 156ms/step - loss: 17.9682 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6501
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1239/Unknown - 202s 156ms/step - loss: 17.4553 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6614
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1279/Unknown - 209s 156ms/step - loss: 16.9745 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6720
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1319/Unknown - 215s 156ms/step - loss: 16.5228 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6820
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1359/Unknown - 221s 156ms/step - loss: 16.0977 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6913
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1399/Unknown - 227s 156ms/step - loss: 15.6969 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7001
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1439/Unknown - 234s 156ms/step - loss: 15.3184 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7085
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1454/Unknown - 239s 158ms/step - loss: 15.1818 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7115Finding embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Text embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Text embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Global Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Local Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Image embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Image embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Logits shape: (None, None)
Text similarities shape: (None, None)
Image similarities shape: (None, None)
Targets shape: (None, None)
Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float16)
1454/1454 [==============================] - 249s 165ms/step - loss: 15.1818 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7115 - val_loss: 2.0801 - val_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - lr: 1.0000e-04
Epoch 2/50
  25/1454 [..............................] - ETA: 1:31 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
  65/1454 [>.............................] - ETA: 2:41 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 105/1454 [=>............................] - ETA: 3:01 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 145/1454 [=>............................] - ETA: 3:06 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 185/1454 [==>...........................] - ETA: 3:06 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 225/1454 [===>..........................] - ETA: 3:03 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 265/1454 [====>.........................] - ETA: 2:59 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 305/1454 [=====>........................] - ETA: 2:54 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt

And then when I change training data to 7000 and val data to 800 then again same behavior. I don't think it's related to data right? I also tried other loss functions.
Epoch 1/50
Finding embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Text embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Text embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Global Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Local Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Image embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Image embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Logits shape: (None, None)
Text similarities shape: (None, None)
Image similarities shape: (None, None)
Targets shape: (None, None)
Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float16)
Finding embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Text embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Text embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Global Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Local Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Image embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Image embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Logits shape: (None, None)
Text similarities shape: (None, None)
Image similarities shape: (None, None)
Targets shape: (None, None)
Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float16)
     39/Unknown - 12s 63ms/step - loss: 347.2369 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1250
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
     79/Unknown - 18s 113ms/step - loss: 226.7587 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1250
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    119/Unknown - 25s 133ms/step - loss: 156.5396 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1239
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    159/Unknown - 31s 140ms/step - loss: 117.9887 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1234
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    199/Unknown - 38s 144ms/step - loss: 94.6929 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1263
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    239/Unknown - 44s 147ms/step - loss: 79.1929 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1266
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    279/Unknown - 51s 149ms/step - loss: 68.1373 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1344
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    319/Unknown - 57s 150ms/step - loss: 59.8542 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1383
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    359/Unknown - 64s 151ms/step - loss: 53.4170 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1368
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    399/Unknown - 70s 152ms/step - loss: 48.2704 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1382
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    439/Unknown - 76s 152ms/step - loss: 44.0618 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1449
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    479/Unknown - 82s 153ms/step - loss: 40.5560 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1550
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    519/Unknown - 89s 153ms/step - loss: 37.5906 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2042
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    559/Unknown - 95s 154ms/step - loss: 35.0496 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2612
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    599/Unknown - 102s 155ms/step - loss: 32.8479 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3105
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    639/Unknown - 108s 155ms/step - loss: 30.9219 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3537
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    679/Unknown - 115s 155ms/step - loss: 29.2229 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3918
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    719/Unknown - 121s 156ms/step - loss: 27.7128 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4256
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    759/Unknown - 128s 156ms/step - loss: 26.3620 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4559
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    799/Unknown - 134s 156ms/step - loss: 25.1464 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4831
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    839/Unknown - 141s 157ms/step - loss: 24.0467 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5077
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    879/Unknown - 147s 157ms/step - loss: 23.0470 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5301
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    919/Unknown - 154s 157ms/step - loss: 22.1344 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5506
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    959/Unknown - 160s 158ms/step - loss: 21.2980 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5693
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    999/Unknown - 167s 158ms/step - loss: 20.5285 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5866
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1039/Unknown - 173s 158ms/step - loss: 19.8182 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6025
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1079/Unknown - 179s 158ms/step - loss: 19.1607 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6172
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1119/Unknown - 185s 157ms/step - loss: 18.5501 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6309
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1159/Unknown - 192s 158ms/step - loss: 17.9817 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6437
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1199/Unknown - 198s 158ms/step - loss: 17.4512 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6555
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1239/Unknown - 205s 158ms/step - loss: 16.9549 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6667
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1279/Unknown - 211s 158ms/step - loss: 16.4897 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6771
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1319/Unknown - 217s 158ms/step - loss: 16.0528 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6869
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1359/Unknown - 224s 158ms/step - loss: 15.6415 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6961
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1399/Unknown - 231s 158ms/step - loss: 15.2537 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7048
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1439/Unknown - 237s 158ms/step - loss: 14.8876 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7130
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
   1474/Unknown - 243s 159ms/step - loss: 14.5834 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7198Finding embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Text embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Text embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Global Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Local Image embeddings shape: (None, 4048)
Image embeddings shape: (None, 8096)
Image embeddings projection shape: (None, 4048)
Logits shape: (None, None)
Text similarities shape: (None, None)
Image similarities shape: (None, None)
Targets shape: (None, None)
Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float16)
1474/1474 [==============================] - 254s 166ms/step - loss: 14.5834 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7198 - val_loss: 2.0801 - val_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - lr: 1.0000e-04
Epoch 2/50
   5/1474 [..............................] - ETA: 1:32 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
  45/1474 [..............................] - ETA: 3:26 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
  85/1474 [>.............................] - ETA: 3:40 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 125/1474 [=>............................] - ETA: 3:33 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 165/1474 [==>...........................] - ETA: 3:27 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 205/1474 [===>..........................] - ETA: 3:19 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 245/1474 [===>..........................] - ETA: 3:13 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 285/1474 [====>.........................] - ETA: 3:07 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 325/1474 [=====>........................] - ETA: 3:00 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 365/1474 [======>.......................] - ETA: 2:55 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 405/1474 [=======>......................] - ETA: 2:48 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 445/1474 [========>.....................] - ETA: 2:42 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 485/1474 [========>.....................] - ETA: 2:36 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 525/1474 [=========>....................] - ETA: 2:29 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0002.ckpt
 561/1474 [==========>...................] - ETA: 2:24 - loss: 2.0801 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000


Providing runnable code will be helpful

You mean I provide you my code to run, but what about the dataset!

As I designed this model similar as CLIP from scratch, so in such models ACCURACY is not the perfect choice to monitor models because we do not have strict labels to measure accuracy. Rather we should focus on loss instead, kindly correct me if I am wrong. Thanks
Epoch 1/50
     79/Unknown - 20s 146ms/step - loss: 318.4557 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    159/Unknown - 33s 155ms/step - loss: 257.9855 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    239/Unknown - 46s 158ms/step - loss: 214.2847 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    319/Unknown - 59s 160ms/step - loss: 183.4361 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    399/Unknown - 73s 161ms/step - loss: 160.7137 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 1: saving model to path/to/your/checkpoint/directory\cp-0001.ckpt
    479/Unknown - 86s 161ms/step - loss: 143.3329 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00

